# Randomizing Playing Deck

Tags: java, arrays

I know there are multiple ways of writing code for this type of question, but I'm trying to understand my Professor's way. He wrote a method that takes the value of an integer in an array and assigns it the value of another random integer in the array, i.e "shuffling a deck":

```
static void shuffle(int[ ] deck) {
//Randomize the order of the elements of deck
//Pick a random card to go in position 0, then position 1, etc.
for(int cardNum=0; cardNum<DECK_SIZE-1; cardNum++){
  //pick a random value randomCardNum from cardNum...DECK_SIZE-1
  int randomCardNum = cardNum+(int)(Math.random()*(DECK_SIZE-cardNum));
  //Swap card and randomCard
  .....
```

What I can't understand is why he would have the `for` loop go until `DECK_SIZE - 1`. There are 52 cards, and I know that an array's last index is n-1, but the last `cardNum` is already not inclusive, so it's going from 0 to 50. I tried taking the `-1` out, I get 52 random cards either way.

I'm not sure if it has to do with `int randomCardNum`, but this seems right as the equation for randomizing numbers in a specific range is :

Min + (int)(Math.random() + (Max-Min))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random shuffling of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

Comment: See the code again, you might be using array as well and a reason for for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your professor's code is correct. Look at the random call:

```
int randomCardNum = cardNum+(int)(Math.random()*(DECK_SIZE-cardNum));
```

When cardNum starts at 0, it chooses one of 52 cards, puts that random one at position 0. Next time through the loop it chooses one of the 51 remaining and puts it next. Then it chooses one of 50 remaining and puts it next, etc. The last time through the loop there are two cards remaining, it chooses one to be first, and then we're done. You add another iteration to the loop it just selects one of the remaining one card, and places it where it already is, to no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, of course. So if I had just put: int randomCardNum = cardNum+(int)(Math.random()*(DECK_SIZE-cardNum + 1)), I wouldn't have had to add the minus one in the for loop would I?

Comment: That would make the code wrong. A proper shuffle HAS to have exactly the sequence of choose one of 52, then one of 51, etc. Any other sequence at all will result in a shuffle that favors some final orderings of cards over others.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to ask your professor, but note that if `cardNum` could go all the way to `51` (the last index), then this line:

```
int randomCardNum = cardNum+(int)(Math.random()*(DECK_SIZE-cardNum));
```

...is guaranteed to result in a `51` in `randomCardNum` on the last iteration, because `DECK_SIZE-cardNum` will be `1`, and so multiplying it by `Math.random()` will give you a value less than `1`, and so casting that value to `int` will result in `0`, and of course `cardNum+0` is `cardnum`.

Since `cardNum` and `randomCardNum` would both be `51` on that last iteration, and there's no point in swapping a card with itself, he stopped one iteration early.

---

**My** question would have been: Why use `DECK_SIZE` rather than `deck.length`, since it introduces a possible maintenance error (changing the size of `deck` but not remembering to change the constant).

Comment: Nice answer, +1. However, he wouldn't change the size of the deck as he is referring to a standard playing card deck, which has 52 cards in it no matter what. Therefor, he wouldn't change the size of the deck.

Comment: @itrollin98: There are all kinds of standard decks. 52 is a common one, but it's not *by far* the only possibility. There's piquet (36 cards), tarot (78; yes, there are tarot games, it's not just for reading the future), canasta (108), ... Of course, `deck` is probably declared somewhere as `int deck[DECK_SIZE];`, so... :-)

Comment: @Crowder however, if you read his entire question you will see this: "There are 52 cards, and I know..."

Comment: @itrollin98: "There are" as in "right now." Always assume requirements will change.

Comment: @Crowder Seeing that this is a class, I would say that they made DECK_SIZE to prevent mistyping or getting confused with `.length` (array) and `.length()` (List).

Comment: @itrollin98: And seeing this is a class, I think teaching good practices is important, hence bringing it up in the first place. This is all massively by-the-bye, though.